# Removing items in List using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of type some entity

List

```
public class OrderLine
{
   public string productCode;
   public int quantity;


}
```

i need to remove items from the above List if the productCode is equal to some products.

```
List<string> ProductsToBeExcluded = new List<string>(){"1234","1237"};
```

so, from `List<OrderLine>` i need to remove products which are equal to 1234 and 1237

i have tried

1. create a `List<string>` from `List<OrderLine>` using

   ```
     List<OrderLine> OrderLines = GetOrderLines();
     var ol = from o in OrderLines
           select o.ProductCode;
   ```

2.

```
  List<string> ProductsToBeExcluded = new List<string>(){"1234","1237"};
   var filtered = OrderLines.Except(ProductsToBeExcluded);
```

how do I proceed further in removing

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you don't need LINQ but can just use `List<T>.RemoveAll` instead

```
OrderLines.RemoveAll(x => ProductsToBeExcluded.Contains(x.ProductCode));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of `List` which accepts predicate

```
OrderLines.RemoveAll(x => ProductsToBeExcluded.Contains(x.ProductCode));
```